# Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter email

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to read the text of a textfield (with the controller emailController) and find out, if the email exists in my collection "admins".

If the email exists in my collection, then it should return true. Otherwise it should return false.

At first I created the firebase request and then I get the result of the query.
If the query is not null, then it should return true. Otherwise it should return false. (when it is null, then there is no email in the collection which is equal to the emailController)

When I run the code I am getting an **error**:

```
Error: [cloud_firestore/invalid-argument] Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter email


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:60283/dart_sdk.js:5660:12)
    at Error._throw (http://localhost:60283/dart_sdk.js:21577:18)
    at Error.throwWithStackTrace (http://localhost:60283/dart_sdk.js:21571:18)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:60283/dart_sdk.js:43533:18)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:60283/dart_sdk.js:43360:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:60283/dart_sdk.js:43366:13)
    at http://localhost:60283/dart_sdk.js:38600:9
```

**code:**

```
Future <bool> getAdminExistance()async{
    var i =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.
    collection('admins').
    orderBy('email').
    where('email', isEqualTo: emailController.text.trim());

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await i.get();

    if(querySnapshot == null){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  }
```

already tried this without orderby and this too:

```
Future <bool> getAdminExistance()async{
    var i =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.
    collection('admins')
    .where('email', isEqualTo: email.text.trim())
    .get()
    .then((value) => value.size > 0 ? true : false);
}
```

But it won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot order your query by any field included in an equality (=) or in clause.

See [Limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) for details.

Comment: So I shouldn't use orderby and just use "where('email', isEqualTo:emailController.text.trim());"? Or how can I do this?